# MYSQL php couple of tables not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

Please Read this carefully so you understand the question. This question is for an assignment in University.

There are two tables, one is an Answer table and the other is a StudentAnswer table. There are 6 fields I am interested in, 4 in Answer table and 2 from StudentAnswer table. Below are tables and their fields and data.

Comment: Your example data looks a little confused.  Should those all be answers for Question 1 in the `Answer` table you show?  `StudentAnswer` only has answers for question 1, presumably from different students.

Comment: Row 1 shows what student u0867587 has put for his answer for question 1. The correct answer is leeds and he put for his answer leeds.            Row 2 shows that student u1231231 answered the same question, obviously the correct answer is still leeds but he selected birmingham.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at subqueries in mysql your eventual answer will probably look somethink like this ...

```
SELECT * FROM Question q
    INNER JOIN (SELECT sa.QuestionId, sa.StudentAnswer, at.AnswerContent FROM StudentAnswer sa LEFT JOIN Answer at ON (sa.StudentAnswer = at.AnswerId AND sa.QuestionId = at.QuestionId) sq ON q.QuestionId = sq.QuestionId
    JOIN Answer a ON sq.QuestionId = a.QuestionId  
WHERE
    (CorrectAnswer = '1')
ORDER BY $orderfield ASC
```

But without a full schema I can't really help, I would also say be careful all my tutors at uni (Huddersfield) were notorious for searching places like this for snippets of their assignments, so I hope this has helped without getting you into trouble

Comment: Im at university of Huddersfield as well. But I am doing my Masters by Research degree now. My Supervisor is Joan Lu don't know if you know her. My second supervisor is Paul Judge. What are you doing?

Comment: I'm curious why you went with a `LEFT JOIN` between `StudentAnswer` and `Answer`.  Is it possible that the student answered with something that wasn't one of the options?  Perhaps the outer join should be between `Question` and `StudentAnswer`, for the case where a student does not answer a question.

Comment: No the student can select only from the answers that matches the question number e.g. if questionid 1 has 4 answers, the student can only choose those 4 answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that left join is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM `StudentAnswer` as sa
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `Question` WHERE correct = 1) as q
  ON `sa`.Questionid = q.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join to `Answer` more than once in your query, just make sure you give it a different alias.  The combination of WHERE clause and JOIN condition you have now gets you the correct answer for a question; think about how else you can relate `StudentAnswer` and `Answer`.

Comment: The problem is not the query, the query works fine. The problem is how do I output it is as a word answer using AnswerContent field and not as an id number from StudentAnswer. How do I make each StudentAnswer id equal to its answer content and display the $row['...']

Comment: The query executes, but it doesn't give the data you need.  In order to get two values for `AnswerContent` in one row, you need to join to `Answer` more than once.